# can I make this query easier?

Tags: sql, query-optimization

What do you mean? can I make this query easier und make the performance better?

```
SELECT DISTINCT tb_Bauteile.ID,
                tb_Bauteile.Name,
                tb_Bauteile.Blatt_nr,
                FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad,
                FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Pfad_Bezeichnung,
                FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Steuergerät,
                FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Kommentar
  FROM ((tb_Pinnummern INNER JOIN tb_Bauteile ON
        tb_Pinnummern.Bauteil = tb_Bauteile.ID) INNER JOIN tb_Fahrzeug ON
        tb_Pinnummern.SG = tb_Fahrzeug.Motor_SG)
 INNER JOIN FehlerCodes_akt_Liste
    ON tb_Bauteile.CDT = FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.CDT
 WHERE (((tb_Bauteile.Blatt_nr) LIKE "5*") AND
       ((tb_Fahrzeug.ID) = forms ! frm_fahrzeug ! id))
 ORDER BY FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad;
```

Thank you very much for your opinions

Comment: Thats a basic select with some vanilla joins and a couple of conditions, you cant really simplify it if that's the data & conditions you need to use. Its performance will be affected by what indexing you create on the joined and (non wildcarded) search columns; http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/create-and-use-an-index-to-improve-performance-HA010210347.aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Reformat it, and remove all the unnecessary parantheses and it's actually quite easy to read (Note that when I wrote this answer, the query in the question was unformatted text!)

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
    tb_Bauteile.ID, tb_Bauteile.Name, tb_Bauteile.Blatt_nr,   
    FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad, FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Pfad_Bezeichnung,
    FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Steuergerät, FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Kommentar
FROM 
      tb_Pinnummern INNER JOIN 
      tb_Bauteile 
      ON tb_Pinnummern.Bauteil = tb_Bauteile.ID INNER JOIN 
           tb_Fahrzeug 
           ON tb_Pinnummern.SG = tb_Fahrzeug.Motor_SG INNER JOIN 
               FehlerCodes_akt_Liste 
               ON tb_Bauteile.CDT = FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.CDT 
WHERE tb_Bauteile.Blatt_nr Like "5*" 
AND   tb_Fahrzeug.ID = [forms]![frm_fahrzeug]![id] 
ORDER BY FehlerCodes_akt_Liste.Fehlerpfad;
```

You can also alias your table names to make those simpler, e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT b.ID, b.Name
FROM tb_Bauteile AS b
WHERE b.Blatt_nr LIKE "5*"
```

Adding indexes on the fields used in your Join and Where clauses would generally improve performance. Note that an index on `tb_Bauteile.Blatt_nr` would improve performance here, as your LIKE clause only has a trailing wildcard. However, if your LIKE clause was `LIKE '*5'` then performance would not be improved.